# D3 map should read second external json data using queue and display on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I have created a map in D3 using queue function to read two json files using the below code. The First json file is the Topojson that helps generate the Map. The Second Json file contains the text that needs to be displayed when mouse hovered over the generated Map.

```
$(function() {
// Assign Canvas size
var margin = { top: 50, left: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50},
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;

// add svg to Canvas
var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin");

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
    .attr('class', 'hidden tooltip');

// Read topojson and external data
d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "tn_topojson.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "tn_data.json")
    .await(ready)

// create a new projection using geoMercator and center it using
// translate and zoom in a certain amount
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .translate([ -7880, 1500 ])
    .scale(6000)

// create a path using geo path using the new projection
var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection)

function ready (error, tn, data){
    console.log(tn);
    console.log(data);
    var constituency = topojson.feature(tn, tn.objects.collection).features;
    console.log(constituency);

    //add the path to the constituency
    svg.selectAll(".constituency")
        .data(constituency)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "constituency")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr('class', function(d){
                    return "constituency " + "c" + d.properties.AC_NO
                })
        .on('mouseover', function(d){
            d3.select(this).classed("selected", true)
            var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map(function(d) {
                return parseInt(d);
            });
            tooltip.classed('hidden', false)
                .attr('style', 'left:' + (mouse[0] + 15) +
                   'px; top:' + (mouse[1] + 30) + 'px')
                .html(d.properties.AC_NAME)
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(d){
            d3.select(this).classed("selected", false)
        })

}

});
```

Console.log function shows that the second json file is loading properly. But how can I get the data from the second json file to display its content to its corresponding path.

the topojson contains constitution id and constitution name that corresponds with the second json file

Comment: can you provide samples of both json tree's? would an alternative approach of merging both jsons before inputting to D3 work better?

Comment: these are the files that I use for the data[tn_data.json](http://interactive.thehindu.com/libraries/tn_data.json), [tn_topojson.json](http://interactive.thehindu.com/libraries/tn_topojson.json) the tn_data would be dynamically generated seperately so it cant be combined into the same file if there is a way to combine it once the data is loaded it may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object (ie hash map) of your data by `acno`.  Then do the look up in your `mouseover` callback:

```
function ready(error, tn, data) {

  // convert to object for easy lookup
  var dataMap = {};
    data.forEach(function(d){
    dataMap[d.acno] = d;
  })

  ...

    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
      d3.select(this).classed("selected", true)
      var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map(function(d) {
        return parseInt(d);
      });

      var fd = dataMap[d.properties.AC_NO],
          html = fd.constituency + "<br>" + fd.district;

      ...
```

---

Full running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.js"></script>
  <style>
    .selected {
      fill: yellow;
    }
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    .tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>
    // Assign Canvas size
    var margin = {
        top: 50,
        left: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 50
      },
      height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;

    // add svg to Canvas
    var svg = d3.select("#map")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin");

    var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
      .attr('class', 'hidden tooltip');

    // Read topojson and external data
    d3.queue()
      .defer(d3.json, "https://jsonblob.com/api/cb3b9a06-eae5-11e6-90ab-a963f5aa6b60")
      .defer(d3.json, "https://jsonblob.com/api/b87933de-eae5-11e6-90ab-b9261b06ccd0")
      .await(ready)

    // create a new projection using geoMercator and center it using
    // translate and zoom in a certain amount
    var projection = d3.geoMercator()
      .translate([-7880, 1500])
      .scale(6000)

    // create a path using geo path using the new projection
    var path = d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection)

    function ready(error, tn, data) {
      
      var dataMap = {};
      data.forEach(function(d){
        dataMap[d.acno] = d;
      })

      var constituency = topojson.feature(tn, tn.objects.collection).features;


      //add the path to the constituency
      svg.selectAll(".constituency")
        .data(constituency)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "constituency")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr('class', function(d) {
          return "constituency " + "c" + d.properties.AC_NO
        })
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
          d3.select(this).classed("selected", true)
          var mouse = d3.mouse(svg.node()).map(function(d) {
            return parseInt(d);
          });
          
          var fd = dataMap[d.properties.AC_NO],
              html = fd.constituency + "<br>" + fd.district;
          
          tooltip.classed('hidden', false)
            .attr('style', 'left:' + (mouse[0] + 15) +
              'px; top:' + (mouse[1] + 30) + 'px')
            .html(html)
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(d) {
          d3.select(this).classed("selected", false)
        })

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```